# Netzke column locking

Tags: extjs4, netzke

I saw a feature in Ext JS document - http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/grid/locking-grid.html. We can lock a column by set the option "locked" according the document, but when I did this in Netzke Grid, the grid disappears. Is there any specific method to achieve this. Below the sample code is given,

```
def configure(c)
    super
    c.model = "Product"
    c.title = "Product List"
    c.columns = [       
          {
          :name => :name,
          :text => "Name",
          :read_only => true,
          :locked => true
          },
          {
          :name => :price,
          :text => "Price"
          },
          {
          :name => :date,
          :text => "Date"
          }
    ]
end
```

Comment: Try this with the latest master (or ext42 branch, if you're using Ext JS 4.2): https://github.com/netzke/netzke-basepack/commit/26348913f2b39dee76c352edaf1677f7296c06f0

Comment: I am using ext 4.1 and in the example link it is given as ext-4.0.1. Is it possible to achieve the functionality with ext 4.1?

Comment: master should work with 4.1

Comment: I have checked this and end up with the same result. Grid is disappearing.

Comment: What errors do you see in Firebug?

Comment: TypeError: this.filters is undefined
  [Break On This Error]  

  }, this);

  criteria (line 273)
  TypeError: this.grid.serverRead is not a function
  [Break On This Error]  

  }, this);

  criteria (line 273)

Comment: Please, update from master again - this should be fixed by now.

Comment: Now the grid is displayed without any content and the loading goes on throwing the same error (firebug).

Comment: I have tried and still this is giving the **same error**